# How to check a large app for ICU update compatibility

Tags: managed-package, datetime, isv, critical-update

A change in the interpretation of Date/Time strings (which originates from Java under the hood) will be enforced in all Salesforce orgs in mid-January 2022. (Find details here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_globalization_enable_icu_cruc.htm&type=5&release=222

---

Given you have a Large **Managed Package** with hundreds of Custom **Objects** and thousands of **Fields**, Formulas and Validations thousands of **classes** and Flows that **potentially create, manipulate or interpret Date/Time values in a soon invalid way**.

> 1. How would you find this out in an effective investigation?
> 2. What would be your steps?
> 3. Which searches on your Git repo (containing your app) would reveal risky areas?

Comment: Which also helped me was learning that changing problematic classes to v.44 would preserve the old Oracle JDK format https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_update_api.htm&type=5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's been some updates so it's best to look at the documentation outside of the previous release notes which can be outdated.

[Go Global with New International Locale Formats](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.icu_migration_overview.htm&type=5) is the parent page and mentions that **enforcement is now for all orgs in Spring '23**. I'd also point out that newer orgs since Winter '20 have been using this format/update and any org can update if they choose.

Off that document are some helpful docs that cover your questions and where the below information is coming from:

- [Considerations for Adopting the ICU Locale Formats](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_changes_considerations.htm&type=5)
- [Custom Code and Locale Format Changes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_code.htm&type=5)
- [Example Code with Locale-Formatted Data](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_code_examples.htm&type=5)
- [Use Locale-Neutral Methods in Code](http://Use%20Locale-Neutral%20Methods%20in%20Code)
- [Update Your Integrations for New Locale Formats](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_code_integrations.htm&type=5)

There's a lot of information there, but it's good to understand what data can  change based on locale which this updates affects

- Address
- Currency
- Date
- DateTime
- Integer
- Name
- Time

So for searching problematic points of your app (or areas to focus testing on), it'd be best to look for situations where you're interacting with those formats/fields in *non-standard* ways

This won't be an exhaustive list (though feel free to add suggestions) but searching should revolve around areas of concerns

- `.format()`
- `.parse(`
- `Date.valueOf()` or `.valueOf()`
- `.formatLong()`
- `$Locale`
- LWCs with `@salesforce/i18n`
- `Pattern` or `Matcher` might show any regex you might be doing against certain data formats that are changing
- List view and report hard-coded filters `AM</value>`, `PM</value>`, `<startDate>`

Those components that return should be checked that there's no custom parsing or expectation of formats that locale may interfere with. The focus for code is on methods that return locale-based results  - a couple examples from the docs:

- `format()` in [Date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_format), [DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format), and [Integer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_integer.htm#apex_System_Integer_format) returns formatting based on the user locale - if you explicitly expect a certain format, make sure to appropriately set it: ex. `.format('h:mm a')`. Searching for the method name with no argument should catch those occurrences.
- Use standard methods when parsing information from those affected data types. ex. Use `.month()`. This applies to formula fields and declarative (ex. `MONTH()`).
- Handle integers and currency values as unformatted until you must format them

---

In short, your steps might look like the following:

1. Update apex and VF to API 45 or later
2. Identify areas of app that rely on affected data (specifically using non-standard methods)
3. Enable and test

Comment: Really helpful and hands-on. Thank you Kris!

Comment: Maybe you want to add Date.valueOf() to your answers list of areas of concern. When we store Locale specific Data as serialized Strings in external databases or even Salesforce records and deserialize it back after the ICU change the Code will break.

Comment: Good call, edited.  Feel free to make edits directly to the answer as you go through it and uncover more.