# Spring 23 release - Changes around ICU Locale formats

Tags: apex, managed-package, api-version, release-update

Salesforce is going to release changes around ICU locale format - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_globalization_enable_icu_cruc.htm&type=5&release=222
Potential impact to look for in the code base
**date, datetime, Integer, Currency, parse(), format()**. Salesforce asks to upgrade the api version to 45.0 or greater of the apex classes , Visualforce pages and apex triggers.
I have following queries with regards to this -

1. Do we need to upgrade the api version to 45.0 of only those files where **Not a locale formatted** code is used - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_locales_code_examples.htm&type=5  or all the files where we have references of these objects?
2. We are managed package provider with 400+ customers and different package versions (from the oldest to the latest there are 140+ different versions) used by our customers How do we effectively upgrade the api version of the impacted files to 45.0 and distribute to our customers. We can upgrade in our latest release , but this means all customers need to upgrade to our latest package version and they will be hesitant to upgrade to the latest version (some of them are at very older version of our package) and even if they are willing it would require large efforts (time and resources) to upgrade and rigorously test through years of version upgrades. Practically, this doesn't seem feasible. Do we have any other options?
3. What are the Objects/Methods (basically keywords) to search for in the code base which could potentially impact? I see good list added in the answer here - [How to check a large app for ICU update compatibility](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365383/how-to-check-a-large-app-for-icu-update-compatibility/365402#365402) Anything to add to this list.

Comment: I believe the point about the API version is that older API versions will continue to use the Java locale formats. You should already be able to test this.